# Why is Laravel 5 including everything under the app folder?

Tags: laravel, include, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I just ran get_included_files() inside a controller's index() method and it turns out it is loading a whopping total of 715 files. Having gone through it in some detail, it seems that it is loading everything inside the app folder in alphabetical order, and of course any dependencies, without regards to whether or not it was actually called. I thought PSR-4 meant that it would only be loaded if it was actually called and not force-loaded on every request.

It this is not normal behavior, is there any way for me to find out what is calling all the files in the app folder in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well at least one major part of the problem has been resolved. It turns out that the Doctrine 2 AnnotationDriver was requiring all the files in the app folder for some reason. I simply commented out line 236:

```
require_once $sourceFile;
```

and about 200 fairly hefty files stopped being included, speeding it up quite a bit. It doesn't seem to have introduced any bugs, at least to the extend that I was able to confirm.

Hope this helps someone!